# Dijsktra worst-case complexity sequence of inputs

Tags: graph, time-complexity, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am looking for a sequence of inputs for the Dijsktra algorigthm implemented with a regular heap, where Dijsktras actual complexity would be Θ((e+v)logv).

I know how to implement Dijsktra and how it works, I also understand that the most time consuming operations are adding a vertex to the heap and changing the distance of a vertex. However, I am not sure how to find a graph (sequence of graphs) that would be the worst case inputs for Dijkstra.

Also if you had any general tips on how to find a sequence of inputs for the worst case complexity, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let vertices be numbered from `1` to `n` and you want to find path from vertex `1` to vertex `n`. Let `e[i][j]` be length of edge, connecting `i` and `j`. Initially `e[1][2] = e[2][3] = ... = e[n - 1][n] = 1`. Now we iterate through the vertices from `n - 2` to `1`. In `i`-th vertex for each `j` in `[i + 2, n]` we make `e[i][j] = e[i][i + 1] + e[i + 1][j] + 1`.

Now we have full graph. In each iteration dijkstra will update `O(n)` vertices, so it's `O(n ^ 2) = O(E)` actions working in `O(log n)`.

So final asymptotics will be `O(n log(n) + E log(n))`